# Consistent connection refused error while using gunicorn within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

So I am using gunicorn webserver on top of a flask webserver. 3 out of 5 requests to the server fail with the following error:

```
Exception: I/O error on POST 
    Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
```

I have 4 worker nodes on a 2 core VM that runs docker container where this gunicorn webserver runs.
Does this exception look familiar to gunicorn folks ?
From the exception, I do understand that there is nothing to listen to the request may be because all the workers are busy taking care of other requests.

Not sure how to resolve this issue. It increased the workers from 4 to 9 but no luck.

The docker file has the following entry for gunicorn

```
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/src/gunicConfig.py", "driverApp:app"]
```

gunicConfig.py looks like this:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 4
```

Comment: Share some more details about your setup. At this point we can only guess.

Comment: I added gunicorn related entry in dockerfile and gunicorn config entries. Not sure what more would be need. Would this suffice ?

Comment: Does gunicorn have a stats server like uWSGI? That should make it trivial to see what the workers are up to. Maybe your client uses a connection pool and keeps connections open until they get booted? Do you run a reverse proxy?

Comment: There is no reverse proxy. client has no connection pool. i'll see what uWSGI tells me about the workers.

Answer (score 0):

With your very little information and with my seeing a similar problem while deploying the server, it looks like either of the following:

1. You do not serve those 3 queries out of 5 - check for complete URL link & extensions. URLs may be malformed
2. Firewall
3. Does your proxy require authentication? If yes, is it authenticated before requesting

Share your trace for more inputs

Comment: along with connection refused error, it also give I/O error

Comment: Share your stack trace, with out seeing the trace that all I can predict.